# Systemdesign: Webserver, API and Database

Tags: java, database, web-services, webserver

Currently i have a website offering some product. The webserver sits on the same system as the database and directly accesses it to retrieve the required information for the HTML frontend. Now i think it is good to separate the database from the webserver via an API server. The reason why i want to use an API server is that it might be possible that future applications, other than the website, will need access to the information on the system.

The system which i want should consist of the following components:

- A database which will store all the required information.
- An API server which will be implemented in Java and should use oauth2 for authorizing user requests. The API server will have the only direct connection to the database.
- A webserver.

So basically what i have in mind is that i want to build my website on top of that API server. The user will register/login/... over the website and the website implementation will internally query the API server as a webservice on behalf of the user. The API server would then return the data from the database. That way the HTML frontend is just an application using the API server and will never itself be in direct contact with the database.

I think that this is an often encountered problem for which a good solution exists. I am unsure if this solution is the way to go though. Could you help me out and/or point me in the right direction from here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not advisable to have a separate API server for a couple of reasons: decreasing performance and increasing compexity of a system. So basically you should avoid this type of solution for as long as possible.

You should definitely read M. Fowler: "Enterprise Architecture Patterns" for inspiration.

Returning to your question: have you considered making this API layer as a module (library)? 
If I haven't convinced you, try reading Java RMI documentation (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at Fowlers book. When I package the API layer as a module I would have to package the module with every application which is based on the API, right? I thought it would be easier to have a central server where the API is hosted from (although it increases system complexity).

Comment: How would your answer change when the API needed to be a publicly available RESTful webapi and not only be bundled with my own applications using it?